# Trying to create a regular expression [ORACLE]

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Good,

I need help to create a regular expression to just take the name and extension of file of the following directories.

```
/home/user/work/file1.dbf
/opt/user/file2.dfb
```

I am trying to create an expression in Oracle12C to only output "`file1.dbf`" and "`file2.dbf`".

I am currently trying to do the regular expression on the next [page](https://regex101.com/) and reading the following [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_regexp.htm#i1007670).

Thanks in advance and I hope I have explained correctly.

Comment: What is your question? If you have a specific problem with existing code, please [edit] your question, include the code and state your specific problem.

Comment: @Xufox The problem is that I have tried many regular expressions and I can not get any that fulfills what I ask. Thank you very much for the comment,

Comment: Do your input strings always represent paths to a file, or might you also have directories there (if done smartly, for this application they should show a `/` right at the end to distinguish them)? You can always add a `where` clause to filter those out first, if they may be present and you don't want them included in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression to do this. A combination of `substr` and `instr` would be sufficient.

`instr(colname,'/',-1)` gets the last occurrence of `/` in the string. And the substring after that position would be the filename as per the data shown.

The filter `instr(colname,'/') > 0` restricts the rows which don't have a `/` in them.

```
select substr(colname,instr(colname,'/',-1)+1) as filename
from tablename
where instr(colname,'/') > 0
```

A regular expression for the same would be

```
select regexp_substr(colname,'(.*/|^)(.+)$',1,1,null,2) as filename
from tablename
```

- `(.*/|^)` - All the characters upto the last `/` occurence in the string or the start of the string if there are no `/` characters.
- `(.+)$` - All the characters after the last `/` if it exists in the string or the full string if `/` doesn't exist.

They are extracted as 2 groups and we are interested in the 2nd group. Hence the argument `2` at the end of `regexp_substr`.

[**`Read about the arguments to REGEXP_SUBSTR here`**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303).

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you for solving my problem and answering so quickly.

Comment: @Randomuser1204281 - for the future, remember vkp's excellent advice: use `substr`, `instr`, `like` and other "standard" string functions and operators whenever possible, and use regular expressions only when it's either not possible to use standard functions and operators, or when using them becomes too cumbersome and hard to manage. You will appreciate the faster execution times!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative regex approach would be to strip everything up to the last `/`:

```
with demo as
     ( select '/home/user/work/file1.dbf' as path from dual union all
       select '/opt/user/file2.dfb' from dual )
select path
     , regexp_replace(path,'^..*/') as filename
from   demo;
```